# Написать функцию, которая убирает комментарии из js-файла не искажая при этом сам код в файле

Tags: javascript, файлы, комментарии

столкнулся с некой проблемой, которую описал в заголовке. Битый час ломаю себе голову. Мысли приходят только следующие. Считывать файл, который передан через форму с типом `file`, с помощью File Reader, присвоить содержимое файла в переменную и через некую `.replace(/\/\*\*[\W\w]*?\*\/(?:\n|.)/g, '')` удалить комментарии.
Но данный вариант мне не очень нравится по ряду причин:
Весь файл считывается в одну цельную строку. И, вероятно, если в коде будут встречаться "`//`" или "`/**/`" то они тоже будут удалены.
Буду рад любому совету. Какими способами можно решить данную задачу?

Comment: Взять uglifyjs. Или взять готовый полноценный парсер (esprima, например) и написать трансформацию. Лезть в исходный код регулярками это гиблое дело. Что-то где-то обязательно сломается

Comment: Можно любой сборщик настроить с модулями по минификации или "уборке" скриптов. Gulp, webpack и прочие. Регулярки - не вариант

Comment: @AlexeyTen Про uglifyjs я знаю. Но задача-то как раз к ним не прибегать.

Comment: @СергейМишин Могу ли я узнать подробнее как это сделать?

Comment: @СергейМишин и там и там под капотом uglify или что-то аналогичное

Comment: @Glechik если задача обрабатывать произвольные js-файлы, то без полноценного парсера не обойтись.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Хорошо. Как по-вашему мне стоит поступить?

Comment: @Glechik, регулярки имеют ограничения по применению: ими невозможно делать разбор серьезно структурированной информации. Используйте uglifyjs. Гляньте [это](https://skalman.github.io/UglifyJS-online/)

Comment: @Glechik я написал в самом первом комментарии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//функция для формирования и скачивания файла
function download(data, filename, type) {
    var file = new Blob([data], {type: type});
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) // IE10+
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, filename);
    else { // Другие
        let a = document.createElement("a"),
            url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = filename;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.body.removeChild(a);
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);  
        }, 0); 
    }
}   

//Главная функция 
function commentsStrip(object){
    var RE_BLOCKS = new RegExp([
      /\/(\*)[^*]*\*+(?:[^*\/][^*]*\*+)*\//.source,           // $1: многострочный коммент
      /\/(\/)[^\n]*$/.source,                                 // $2 однострочный коммент
      /"(?:[^"\\]*|\\[\S\s])*"|'(?:[^'\\]*|\\[\S\s])*'|`(?:[^`\\]*|\\[\S\s])*`/.source,
      /(?:[$\w\)\]]|\+\+|--)\s*\/(?![*\/])/.source,           // - оператор деления
      /\/(?=[^*\/])[^[/\\]*(?:(?:\[(?:\\.|[^\]\\]*)*\]|\\.)[^[/\\]*)*?\/[gim]*/.source
      ].join('|'),                                            // - РЕГУЛЯРКА
      'gm'  
    );

    //проверка на поддержку браузером FILE API
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.Blob) {
        var content = ''; //переменная для записи содержимого файла
        var file = object.files[0]; // первый элемент массива файлов
        var reader = new FileReader();
        //при успешном прогружении файла записать содержимое в переменную
        reader.onload = function(){
            content = reader.result;
            //удалить комментарии
            let a = content.replace(RE_BLOCKS, function (match, mlc, slc) {
                                                return mlc ? ' ' :         // многострочный коммент (пробел)
                                                slc ? '' :          // одно/многострочный
                                                match;             
            });
            //Вернуть функцию для скачивания готового документа
            return(download(a, file.name, file.type));
        }
        //считать как простой текст
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }else{
        alert("Нужные File API не поддерживаются вашим браузером!");
    }
}
```